# Incremental Maximum Entropy Classifier

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

Can the algorithm that's used to build a maximum entropy classifier be modified to function incrementally, or is it by definition a batch process? I've found [a few](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.classify.maxent-module.html) [open source](http://maxent.sourceforge.net/about.html) implementations, but they're all batch processes, and even after inspecting the code, I can't envision how I'd modify them to function incrementally. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to train a maximum entropy classifier by an incremental process. I think the most popular training scheme would probably be stochastic gradient descent. You also might want to use the term logistic regression instead of max-entropy to help with the Googling.

From a brief search, perhaps these might be of some help?

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/logistic-regression/read-me.html

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-228